# Running time of permutation function

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, recursion, permutation

My book provides the following code for a function that computes all the permutations of a string of unique characters (see code below), and says that the running time is O(n!), "since there are n! permutations."

I don't understand how they've computed the running time as O(n!). I assume they mean "n" is the length of the original string. I think that the running time should be something like O((n + 1)XY), since the getPerms function will be called (n + 1) times, and X and Y can represent the running times of the outer and inner for loops respectively. Can someone explain to me why this is wrong / the book's answer is right?

Thanks.

```
public static ArrayList<String> getPerms(String str)
{
    if (str == null)
        return null;

    ArrayList<String> permutations = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (str.length() == 0)
        permutations.add("");
        return permutations;

    char first = str.charAt(0); //first character of string
    String remainder = str.substring(1); //remove first character

    ArrayList<String> words = getPerms(remainder);
    for (String word: words)
    {
        for (i = 0; i <= word.length(); i++)
        {
            String s = insertCharAt(word, first, i);
            permutations.add(s)
        }
    }

    return permutations;

}

public static String insertCharAt(String word, char c, int j)
{
    String start = word.substring(0, i);
    String end = word.substring(i); 
    return start + c + end;
}
```

Source: Cracking the Coding Interview

Comment: @shekharsuman That is the only code provided in the book. I agree it is incomplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From our intuition, it is clear that there is no existing algorithm that generate permutation of N items that perform better than O(n!) because there are n! possibility.

You can reduce the recursive code into recurrence equation because `gePerm(n)` where n is a string with n length will call `getPerm(n-1)`. Then, we use all the value returns by it and put a inner loop that loop N times. So we have

> P<sub>n</sub> = nP<sub>n-1</sub>
>   P<sub>1</sub> = 1

It is easy to see that P<sub>n</sub> = n! by telescoping the equation.

---

If you have hard times visualize how we come up with this equation, you can also think of this way

```
ArrayList<String> words = getPerms(remainder);
for (String word: words)                          // P(n-1)
{
    for (i = 0; i <= word.length(); i++)          // nP(n-1)
    {
        String s = insertCharAt(word, first, i);
        permutations.add(s)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The count of permutations of `N` elements is `N * (N - 1) * (N - 2) * ... * 2 * 1`, i.e. `N!`.

First character can be any one of `N` characters. Next character can be one of remained `N - 1` characters. Now we have `N * (N - 1)` possible cases already.

So, continuing we'll have `N * (N - 1) * (N - 2) * ...` cases at each step.

Cause the count of permutations of `N` elements is `N!`, then there isn't an implementation that can permutate an array of length `N` faster than N!.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain your sentence: "First character can be any one of N characters"? I think the book takes the "first character" to be only the character at the start of the string. Therefore, I would think that first character can only be one possible character, not any one of N characters?

Comment: Look at short example with string "123". The implementation fixes first character '1' then calls itself recursively and receives strings "23" and "32". Then it inserts first character into these string at all possible positions: "123", "213", 231" for first string and "132", "312", "321" for second string. So first character is not fixed in result actually.